# how to style on the most right in <li>s?

Tags: html, css

cant figure out why this code dont work, it's still on left:

```
<ul style="list-style: none; width: 200px;" >
<li class="item" ><p>hello world</p></li>
<li class="item"><p>hello world</p></li>
<li class="item"><p>hello world</p></li>
</ul>
```

my css:

```
.item {
 position: relative; 
 right: 0px; 
 margin-top: 2px;
}
```

I tried transferring the style of li on p and both but it still has no effect. Help?

Comment: `relative` positioning won't do much, just make the li relative and then the p tag `absolute` and now add positioning , it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `text-align: right` on your `<ul>`:

```html
<ul style="list-style: none; width: 200px; text-align:right" >
  <li class="item" ><p>hello world</p></li>
  <li class="item"><p>hello world</p></li>
  <li class="item"><p>hello world</p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: dont know why I dont have text-align in mind. pretty simple. thanks

Comment: the "right: 0px;" is used for absolute elements, that's why it doesn't work in your case

Comment: @DamienBannerot aha, thought it'd work on relative elements in this case.

Answer (score 0):

add `text-align:right` in `.item` property

```css
.item {
 position: relative; 
 margin-top: 2px;
 text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<ul style="list-style: none; width: 200px;" >
<li class="item" ><p>hello world</p></li>
<li class="item"><p>hello world</p></li>
<li class="item"><p>hello world</p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There's no need for `position: relative` here.

Comment: yes i know that but i add only `text-align:right` code.